# Unexpected Postgres query behavior when referring to the results of UPDATE inside a CTE

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, transactions, sql-update

```
WITH deleted_files AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM files
  WHERE id = $1
), updated_links AS (
  UPDATE links l
    SET object = JSONB_SET(object, 
                           '{files}', 
                           (SELECT jsonb_agg(elem)
                            FROM files nested,
                                 jsonb_array_elements(object -> 'files') elem
                            WHERE nested.id = l.id
                            AND elem ->> 'name' != (SELECT name FROM deleted_files)),
                            true
                  ) 
   RETURNING id, object
)
DELETE FROM links 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM updated_links 
             WHERE object IS NULL);
```

I am using Postgres 14 and running this query inside of a Goland query session with READ COMMITTED isolation level.

The idea of this query is to:

1. Get deleted file names by `id`
2. Update the `object` JSONB column in the table `links`
3. Delete rows from `links` where after this update the value of `object` (JSONB field) is `NULL`.

As a result of this query, I still see rows with NULL `object` fields even though if I just do something like `SELECT id FROM updated_links WHERE object is NULL` instead of the delete statement, I get the right results.

It seems that the statement after CTEs doesn't yet see the updated columns but that is a bit strange given that the changes are apparently visible to SELECT statements.

What am I missing here?

Update (1)

Actually, the whole JSONB-related logic can be omitted completely here and simplified to this:

```
WITH deleted_files AS (
SELECT name FROM files
WHERE id = $1
), updated_links AS (
UPDATE links SET object = NULL RETURNING *
)
DELETE FROM links WHERE object IS NULL;
```

I have no idea why the DELETE statement has no clue about the NULL `object` value in this case.

Update (2):

I don't think this is important but I am using Postgres from GCP's CloudSQL

Comment: From docs [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH): *The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed at the same time. This implies that the effects of a data-modifying statement in WITH cannot be seen from other parts of the query, other than by reading its RETURNING output. If two such data-modifying statements attempt to modify the same row, the results are unspecified.*

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't it mean that in theory I can use RETURNING in the update CTE, select rows with NULL object value and then delete by id ? The documentation says that should work

Comment: Tried with no success

Comment: Add the code from your attempt to the question.

Comment: It's already there, isn't it? In my first block of code, I do exactly that: use RETURNING in the updating CTE and then try to delete by these ids in the DELETE statement.

Comment: Aah, I missed that as I went to the simplified query.

Comment: I have found a piece in the documentation that probably explains why I shouldn't be writing the query this way as the result is unpredictable: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING

Comment: Yeah the relevant part: *This also applies to deleting a row that was already updated in the same statement: only the update is performed. Therefore you should generally avoid trying to modify a single row twice in a single statement.*. Information learned.

Comment: Yeah, the lesson is learned :) 
I posted my own answer below

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) says:

> Trying to update the same row twice in a single statement is not
> supported. Only one of the modifications takes place, but it is not
> easy (and sometimes not possible) to reliably predict which one. This
> also applies to deleting a row that was already updated in the same
> statement: only the update is performed. Therefore you should
> generally avoid trying to modify a single row twice in a single
> statement. In particular avoid writing WITH sub-statements that could
> affect the same rows changed by the main statement or a sibling
> sub-statement. The effects of such a statement will not be
> predictable.

To sum up, in order to achieve the result I want above, I need to use several statements within one transaction or, as I decided in the end, write a trigger function so that after every update, rows with NULL `object` values are deleted from the table.